# How to Create Random Moving Numbers

Tags: vb.net, random, timer

How to Create  Random Moving Numbers that can stop on 5 seconds, It keeps on generating random numbers and stop when timers get to 5 seconds

Comment: What are `Random Moving Numbers`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.Timers.Timer` with the `Random` class:

If you are using Windows Forms, this is very simple. Use the Timer control and randomize each few milliseconds:

```
Dim sec as Decimal
Dim targetSeconds as Integer = 5
Dim rnd as New Random()

'Omitting the parameters of the event
Private Sub timer_tick() Handles Timer.Tick
    sec = sec + Timer.Interval
    Label.Text = rnd.Next()
    If sec >= targetSeconds Then
        Timer.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you are on Console Application, however, you are going to assign a variable as `System.Timers.Timer`, add the Tick event handler and use the same code as above. Make sure to call `Start()` to start the timer